# How to search between dates?

Tags: vb6

iam using ms access database and i want to get data between two dates

```
stdate= starting date

edate=end date
```

iam using the code below.

```
Private Sub Label3_Click()
DataGrid1.Visible = True
Dim stdate As Date
Dim edate As Date
Format = stdate("mm/dd/yyyy")
Format = edate("mm/dd/yyyy")
stdate = Text1.Text
edate = Text2.Text

Adodc1.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM sales_info WHERE  date BETWEEN &stdate& and              &edate& "
Adodc1.Refresh
End Sub
```

errors iam getting are:

```
syntax error expected array(in format statement)

 missing operator in query expression date.
```

thanks

plz help

iam a beginner

Answer (score 1):

This code should work-

```
Private Sub Label3_Click()
  DataGrid1.Visible = True
  Dim stdate As String
  Dim edate As String
  stdate = Format(Text1.Text, "mm/dd/yyyy")
  edate = Format(Text2.Text, "mm/dd/yyyy")

  Adodc1.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM [sales_info] WHERE [date] BETWEEN #" & stdate & " and " & edate & "]"
  Adodc1.Refresh
End Sub
```

I also agree with @Joe in that you should not use date for your column name as it is typically a reserved word.  The [] get around that, but it will make life tougher in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

try to change name of your field because **date** is a reserved keyword.

After change the format of your date to use a format compliant to VB6 (with #)

Answer (score 0):

The lines Format = stdate("mm/dd/yyyy") and Format = edate("mm/dd/yyyy")
don't look like valid VB6 to me.

You will need to build the query string by gluing the bits together, the interpreter cannot see inside the quotation marks to understand that you want a variable there

"SELECT * FROM sales_info WHERE  date BETWEEN #" & stdate & "# and #" & edate &"#"

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works. :)

```
    Adodc1.RecordSource = = "SELECT * " & "FROM tbl " & _
        "WHERE Date >= #" & stdate & "# AND Date <= #" & edate & "# "
    Adodc1.Requery
```

Answer (score 0):

Table_1BindingSource.Filter="DateColumnName>=# & DateTimePicker1.text & "# and DateColumName<=#" & DateTimePicker2.text & "#"